# SQL Results output as a grid/single row resultset to multiple rows

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008, resultset

Is it possible to output a resultset as a grid? For example I output the following resultset using sql:

```
col1    col2    col3    col4    col5    col6    col7    col8    col9
10      23      54      12      23      45      56      24      2
```

but instead of the output forming one long row is there a function I can use to get it to output as:

```
col1    col2    col3
10      23      54
12      23      45
56      24      2
```

So I'm essentially breaking the results row every three columns.

Also the output would be a combinations of various calculations performed on the data in joined sql tables just in case this makes a difference.

Comment: What if there are 10 columns, i.e. col10 as well? so col2 and col3 be null?

Comment: Hi @techdo In the real world example this will be 17 by 17 grid and there will never be any null values. The rows and columns will be fixed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you don't mind manually defining the columns to split, and the format will remain fixed you can use `CROSS APPLY ... VALUES` to unpivot the data. e.g.

```
SELECT  c.Col1, c.Col2, c.Col3
FROM    T
        CROSS APPLY
        (   VALUES
                (Col1, Col2, Col3),
                (Col4, Col5, Col6),
                (Col7, Col8, Col9)
        ) c (Col1, Col2, Col3);
```

**[Example on SQL Fiddle](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!3/41edc/1)**